# Selenium IDE: How to record opening the developer tools and type a command to console

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm pretty new to Selenium IDE, and I want to automate an operation of opening developer tools (F12) and type something in the console. Unfortunately, when I click the record button and I open the dev tools and type there something, I don't see that something is recorded.

This is the recording button:

[image]

Do you know how it can be done?

Comment: That means you are comfortable with opening Console Right?

Comment: yes..............

Comment: And you want to record with? Because you mention that, When I press recording? Where you start?

Comment: I click recording button, then click F12, then type "alert('hello world')" in the console and then click the recording button again (and stop the recording)

Comment: But what is recording button any third party recording software?

Comment: I added a picture

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think that this is possible, sorry. It's nearly the same issue as it is with windows popups (for example the download-prompt) because Selenium IDE cannot "interact" with the browser itself or the OS.

Selenium IDE can just interact with javascript-popups (like alert) from the web application.